# Problem of "Memory limit exceeded" and "Time limit exceeded" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

I have a problem to solve on the [online judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming#Overview). Its solution is to make the sum of the integer for example input 4, so 1+2+3+4 the output 10. For another example, the input is 10, so get sum of 1 to 10 to get in the output 55 and so on.

But when I used a *list* to store numbers and make sum(List), it gave me a *"Memory limit exceeded"*.

Here is the code:

```
n = int(raw_input())
lista = []
for x in range(1, n+1):
   lista.append(x)
print sum(lista)
```

I tried another solution not to save in a list to avoid the memory exceeded, so I tried this:

```
n = int(raw_input())
sum = 0
for i in xrange(1, n+1):
   sum = sum + i
print sum
```

But I get "Time limit exceeded". What is the solution to this problem?

Note that the range of number to the input and it will test on is 1≤ N ≤ 10^9. When I try the 10^9, it takes a really long time to get the answer.

Another note is that the time limit per test is 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an arithmetic progression and computes as S = ½(a1 + an)n,
where a1 is first member, which is 1 in this case. an is the last
member which is n in this case.

```
def arthimPSum(n):
    return round((1 + n)*n *0.5)

print(arthimPSum(10**9))
```

#### Output

```
500000000500000000
```

Comment: so what is should to do. write the full code that if i put it not to get any of these 2 bugs

Comment: @AmrKamal your second version is better, since there is no append to list. but use total += 1, and not total = total + 1. I have tested on python3. that is why range but not xrange.

Comment: n=int(raw_input())
sum=0
for i in xrange(1,n+1):
    sum+=1
print sum i write it like that but i not get the sum of 10 when i input 4 i want to get sum of 1+2+3+4 to get 10 any number make that to it and so on

Comment: @AmrKamal fixed. total+=i  now, was wrongly total=+i in answer

Comment: you do not  understand  the problem is or the test i have to give input for example 4 i want to sum from 1 to 4 to get output 10 for another example input 10 to get sum from 1 to 10 the result will be in output 55 when i upload the 2 code in problem i get this 2 error memory exceed when i use list and time exceed when i use the second code that is it i want to solve this problem and in the problem say that time not exceed  1 second per test and not to exceed the memory limit per test is 64 megabyte ?

Comment: the problem not an erorr  on run  the python the problem on the online judge that i submit the code to it . how to make this condition, the Time and the Memory to the Online judge to Accept the code

Comment: @AmrKamal most efficient solution would be use reduce add and not a list but a generator expression. Other than that  I do not know what else could be done. I will update now so that solution will have generator expression.

Comment: @AmrKamal, you got your 1 second. To stupid me it occurred after a while that it is just an arithmetic progression. Take a look.

Comment: thank you bro its really does not take any time to run :D

Answer (score 0):

its just an arithmetic progression where you find the sum of n numbers so basically formula is

sum = n/2(2a+(n-1)d)

pass the first number that is a =1 and n is the total numbers, d is difference which is 1 .
it is simplified as n/2(2+(n-1)) = 0.5* n *(n+1)